# Custom posts type for individual pages?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, cms, post-editor

I am trying to make a wordpress site with an idiot-proof backend CMS.  I have built several relatively small wordpress sites, but now have moved on to a larger project and want to do it *right*.

There will be several (maybe as much as 10+) pages each with unique structures and elements (different numbers of pictures, and text-content areas).  There will be maybe a couple dozen other pages with more standard layouts (just some text into a template).  Ideally, I would want the "edit page" area of each 'unique' page to have its own unique set-up.

For Example, heres a few sample pages:

Home page

- List item
- 2 sections of text
- 6 photos with captions (captions are split in 2 sections each for 2 fonts and a line break)

About page

- 2 images (no captions)
- 1 main text section
- 1 video

Videos page

- 2 text sections
- 1 picture
- any number of videos

Now its pretty clear to me that for the videos page, I should create a custom-post-type video, where the user can put in the url for a YouTube video, some descriptive text etc... and then pull all of those video posts into my videos page.

What is unclear to me is whether I should make a 'homepage' custom-post-type with only one post (the homepage) and do the same thing for other pages with unique elements/layouts.

I hope this is clear enough, I can elaborate more or create some images of what I have in mind, but this seems to be getting rather lengthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the default "Pages" is easy enough for people to understand..it is where you edit each page.

You can make a "Videos" page template for a Videos page that can show the page content at top "your text areas" and then calls a listing of all the custom post type Videos you created. I just worked on a site with CPT for videos so here is some code you can play with..it creates a taxonomy for Videos, and then the video types, and then adds some extra features to the back-end for adding videos. It is kind of long but just copy and past into your functions.php file and then edit out the bits you don't want.

*Additional Thoughts****
For the 10+ pages that have the more complex layouts, a new custom-post-type would be appropriate, especially if you can think of a group of generic metafields and boxes you can use that can be put to work on each of the pages. For example:
A custom post type called "Special Pages"
The edit page for "Special Pages" will a set of meta-fields with some generic labeling:
Images- "Image 1" "Image 2"...
Text: "Text 1" "text 2"

You can add the simple-video-editor to this post type to get the Video Fields
Here is a blog-post a guy made about creating just such a special Page:
http://sicdigital.com/2010/07/create-custom-post-type-for-image-upload-wordpress3/

```
<?php
/*******************************************************************Create a Custom Taxonomy ******************************/
        add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );  
        function build_taxonomies() {  
            register_taxonomy( 
            'video_types', 
            'videos',
           array( 'hierarchical' => true, 
            'label' => 'Video Types',
            'query_var' => true, 
            'rewrite' => true ) );  
        }
        // Add to admin_init function
        add_filter("manage_edit-video_types_columns", 'theme_columns'); 
        function theme_columns($theme_columns) {
            $new_columns = array(
                'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
                'name' => __('Name'),
        //      'description' => __('Description'),
        //      'slug' => __('Slug'),
                'posts' => __('Posts')
                );
            return $new_columns;
        }
        /*******************************************************************Create a Custom Post Type******************************/
        add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
        function create_post_type() {
        //start the post type
        register_post_type( 'videos',
        array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Videos' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Video' ),
        'slug' =>  __( 'videos' ),
        'with_front'=>  __( false ),
        'new_item' =>  __( 'New Video' ),
        'add_new_item'=>  __( 'Add New Video' ),
        'edit_item'=>  __( 'Edit Video' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'supports' => array('title','thumbnail',  'videoembed')
        )
        );
        //end this post type
        }/*---end create post type---*/

        // Customise edit columns for video post type

        add_filter("manage_edit-videos_columns", "prod_edit_columns");
        add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "prod_custom_columns");

        function prod_edit_columns($columns){
        $columns = array(
        "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
        "title" => "Video Title",
        "video_type" => "Video Type",
        );
        return $columns;
        }
        function prod_custom_columns($column){
        global $post;
        switch ($column)
        {
        case "video_type":
        echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'video_types', '', ', ','');
        break;
        }
        }
        // Make these columns sortable
        function sortable_columns() {
          return array(
          "video_type" => "video_types",
            "title" => "title"
          );
        }
        add_filter( "manage_edit-videos_sortable_columns", "sortable_columns" );
        // Filter the request to just give posts for the given taxonomy, if applicable.
        function taxonomy_filter_restrict_manage_posts() {
            global $typenow;

            // If you only want this to work for your specific post type,
            // check for that $type here and then return.
            // This function, if unmodified, will add the dropdown for each
            // post type / taxonomy combination.
            $post_types = get_post_types( array( '_builtin' => false ) );
            if ( in_array( $typenow, $post_types ) ) {
                $filters = get_object_taxonomies( $typenow );
                foreach ( $filters as $tax_slug ) {
                    $tax_obj = get_taxonomy( $tax_slug );
                    wp_dropdown_categories( array(
                        'show_option_all' => __('Show All '.$tax_obj->label ),
                        'taxonomy'    => $tax_slug,
                        'name'        => $tax_obj->name,
                        'orderby'     => 'name',
                        'selected'    => $_GET[$tax_slug],
                        'hierarchical'    => $tax_obj->hierarchical,
                        'show_count'      => false,
                        'hide_empty'      => true
                    ) );
                }
            }
        }
        add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'taxonomy_filter_restrict_manage_posts' );
        function taxonomy_filter_post_type_request( $query ) {
          global $pagenow, $typenow;
          if ( 'edit.php' == $pagenow ) {
            $filters = get_object_taxonomies( $typenow );
            foreach ( $filters as $tax_slug ) {
              $var = &$query->query_vars[$tax_slug];
              if ( isset( $var ) ) {
                $term = get_term_by( 'id', $var, $tax_slug );
                $var = $term->slug;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        add_filter( 'parse_query', 'taxonomy_filter_post_type_request' );
        /*---end edit columns---*/
    /************************************************************ Simple Video Editor   and Video Thumbnails plugins   *******/
    //HOTFIX FOR VIMEO VIDEOS NOT SHOWING UP USING LINK
    function fix_vimeo_oembed_providers( $providers ) {
    $providers['#http://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/.*#i'] = array( 'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.{format}', true );
    return $providers;
    }
    add_filter('oembed_providers', 'fix_vimeo_oembed_providers');
    /**
     * Gets the embed code for a video.
     *
     * @param $postID The post ID of the video
     * @return The embed code
     */
    function p75GetVideo($postID, $width= ''){
        global $wp_embed;
        // legacy support...
        if ( $videoURL = get_post_meta($postID, 'videoembed', true) ) return $videoURL;
        if ( $videoEmbed = get_post_meta($postID, '_videoembed_manual', true ) ) return $videoEmbed;

        $videoURL = get_post_meta($postID, '_videoembed', true);
        if ( !($videoWidth = get_post_meta($postID, '_videowidth', true)) )
            $videoWidth = get_option('p75_default_player_width');
        if ( !($videoHeight = get_post_meta($postID, '_videoheight', true)) )
            $videoHeight = get_option('p75_default_player_height');

        $height = intval ( $width * ( $videoHeight / $videoWidth ) );

        if (empty($width)){$width = $videoWidth;}
        if (empty($height)){$height = $videoHeight;}
        return $wp_embed->shortcode( array('width' => $width, 'height' => $height), $videoURL );
    }
    /**
     * Returns true if post has a video.
     *
     * @param $postID The post ID
     * @return True if post has a video, false otherwise
     */
    function p75HasVideo($postID)
    {
        return (bool) 
            (
                get_post_meta($postID, '_videoembed', true) ||
                get_post_meta($postID, '_videoembed_manual', true) ||
                get_post_meta($postID, 'videoembed', true)
            );
    }

    // Register the custom JW Media Player embed handler.

    function p75_jw_player_handler( $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr )
    {
        static $counter = 1;

        if ( !empty($rawattr['width']) && !empty($rawattr['height']) ) { 
            $width  = (int) $rawattr['width'];
            $height = (int) $rawattr['height'];
        } else {
            list( $width, $height ) = wp_expand_dimensions( 
                get_option('p75_default_player_width'), 
                get_option('p75_default_player_height'), 
                $attr['width'], $attr['height'] );
        }

        $flashvars = get_option('p75_jw_flashvars');
        if ( !empty($flashvars) && substr($flashvars, 0, 1)!='&' )
            parse_str( $flashvars, $vars );

        $file_loc = get_option('p75_jw_files');
            if ( substr($file_loc, -1)!='/' )
                $file_loc = $file_loc . '/';

        $res = "
    <script type='text/javascript' src='{$file_loc}swfobject.js'></script>
    <div id='videoContainer-" . $counter . "'>This text will be replaced</div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var so = new SWFObject('{$file_loc}player.swf','ply','" . esc_attr($width) . "','" . esc_attr($height) . "','9','#000000');
    so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
    so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
    so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
    so.addVariable('file','" . esc_attr($url) . "');\n";
        if ( $vars )
        {
            foreach ( $vars as $key => $val )
                $res .= "so.addVariable('$key','" . rawurlencode($val) . "');\n";
        }
        $res .= "so.write('videoContainer-" . $counter++ . "');
    </script>\n";
        return $res;
    }

    wp_embed_register_handler( 
        'p75_jw_player', 
        '#http://.*\.(flv|mp4)#i', 
        'p75_jw_player_handler' );


    // RSS feed filter to include videos

    function p75_feed_video_filter($content, $feed) {
        global $post;

        if ( p75HasVideo($post->ID) )
            return p75GetVideo($post->ID) . $content;

        return $content;
    }

    add_filter('the_content_feed', 'p75_feed_video_filter', 10, 2);


    /**
     * Plugin activation. Set default player width
     * and height if not present.
     */
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'p75_sveActivate');

    function p75_sveActivate()
    {
        global $wpdb;

        // Set default player width and height if not present.
        add_option('p75_default_player_width', '670');
        add_option('p75_default_player_height', '400');
        update_option('p75_sve_version', '2.0');
    }

    /**
     * Post admin hooks
     */
    add_action('do_meta_boxes', "p75_videoAdminInit");
    add_action('admin_menu', "p75_videoAdminOptionsInit");
    add_action('save_post', 'p75_saveVideo');

    /**
     * Add video posting widget and options page.
     */
    function p75_videoAdminInit($page)
    {
        if( function_exists("add_meta_box") )
        {
            $post_types = explode(',',get_option('p75_post_types'));
            if ( in_array( $page, $post_types ) ){ add_meta_box("p75-video-posting", "Post Video Options", "p75_videoPosting", $page, "advanced"); }
        }
    }
    function p75_videoAdminOptionsInit()
    {
        add_options_page('Simple Video Embedder Options', 'Video Options', 8, 'videooptions', 'p75_videoOptionsAdmin');
    }

    /**
     * Code for the meta box.
     */
    function p75_videoPosting()
    {
        global $post_ID, $wp_embed;
        $videoURL = get_post_meta($post_ID, '_videoembed', true);
        $videoHeight = get_post_meta($post_ID, '_videoheight', true);
        $videoWidth = get_post_meta($post_ID, '_videowidth', true);
        $videoEmbed = get_post_meta($post_ID, '_videoembed_manual', true);


    ?>





        <div style="float:left; margin-right: 5px;">
            <label for="p75-video-url"><?php _e("Video URL"); ?>:</label><br />
            <input style="width: 300px; margin-top:5px;" type="text" id="p75-video-url" name="p75-video-url" value="<?php echo $videoURL; ?>" tabindex='100' />
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; margin-right: 5px;">
            <label for="p75-video-width3"><?php _e("Width"); ?>:</label><br />
            <input style="margin-top:5px;" type="text" id="p75-video-width3" name="p75-video-width" size="4" value="<?php echo $videoWidth; ?>" tabindex='101' />
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;">
            <label for="p75-video-height4"><?php _e("Height"); ?>:</label><br />
            <input style="margin-top:5px;" type="text" id="p75-video-height4" name="p75-video-height" size="4" value="<?php echo $videoHeight; ?>" tabindex='102' />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div style="margin-top:10px;">
              <label for="p75-video-embed"><?php _e("Embed Code"); ?>: (<?php _e("Overrides Above Settings"); ?>)</label><br />
              <textarea style="width: 100%; margin:5px 2px 0 0;" id="p75-video-embed" name="p75-video-embed" rows="4" tabindex="103"><?php echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($videoEmbed)); ?></textarea>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input id="p75-remove-video" type="checkbox" name="p75-remove-video" /> <label for="p75-remove-video"><?php _e("Remove video"); ?></label>
        </p>

    <?php
        // Video preview.
        if ( $videoURL )
        {
            echo '<div style="margin-top:10px;">' . __("Video Preview") . ': (' . __("Actual Size") . ')<br /><div id="video_preview" style="padding: 3px; border: 1px solid #CCC;float: left; margin-top: 5px;">';
            echo p75GetVideo($post_ID);
            echo '</div></div><div class="clear"></div>';
        }
        else if ( $videoEmbed )
        {
            echo '<div style="margin-top:10px;">' . __("Video Preview") . ': (' . __("Actual Size") . ')<br /><div id="video_preview" style="padding: 3px; border: 1px solid #CCC;float: left; margin-top: 5px;">';
            echo stripslashes($videoEmbed);
            echo '</div></div><div class="clear"></div>';
        }
    ?>

    <p style="margin:10px 0 0 0;"><input id="publish" class="button-primary" type="submit" value="<?php _e("Update Post"); ?>" accesskey="p" tabindex="5" name="save"/></p>

    <?php
    }

    /**
     * Saves the thumbnail image as a meta field associated
     * with the current post. Runs when a post is saved.
     */
    function p75_saveVideo( $postID ) {
        global $wpdb;

        // Get the correct post ID if revision.
        if ( $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_type FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID=$postID")=='revision')
            $postID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_parent FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID=$postID");

        // Trim white space just in case.
        $_POST['p75-video-embed'] = trim($_POST['p75-video-embed']);
        $_POST['p75-video-url'] = trim($_POST['p75-video-url']);
        $_POST['p75-video-width'] = trim($_POST['p75-video-width']);
        $_POST['p75-video-height'] = trim($_POST['p75-video-height']);

        if ( $_POST['p75-remove-video'] )
        {
            // Remove video
            delete_post_meta($postID, '_videoembed');
            delete_post_meta($postID, '_videowidth');
            delete_post_meta($postID, '_videoheight');
            delete_post_meta($postID, '_videoembed_manual');
        }
        elseif ( $_POST['p75-video-embed'] )
        {
            // Save video embed code.
            if( !update_post_meta($postID, '_videoembed_manual', $_POST['p75-video-embed'] ) )
                add_post_meta($postID, '_videoembed_manual', $_POST['p75-video-embed'] );
            delete_post_meta($postID, '_videoembed');
            delete_post_meta($postID, '_videowidth');
            delete_post_meta($postID, '_videoheight');
        }
        elseif ( $_POST['p75-video-url'] )
        {
            // Save video URL.
            if( !update_post_meta($postID, '_videoembed', $_POST['p75-video-url'] ) )
                add_post_meta($postID, '_videoembed', $_POST['p75-video-url'] );
            delete_post_meta($postID, '_videoembed_manual');

            // Save width and height.
            if ( is_numeric($_POST['p75-video-width']) )
            {
                if( !update_post_meta($postID, '_videowidth', $_POST['p75-video-width']) )
                    add_post_meta($postID, '_videowidth', $_POST['p75-video-width']);
            }
            else if ( empty($_POST['p75-video-width']) )
                delete_post_meta($postID, '_videowidth');

            if ( is_numeric($_POST['p75-video-height']) )
            {
                if( !update_post_meta($postID, '_videoheight', $_POST['p75-video-height']) )
                    add_post_meta($postID, '_videoheight', $_POST['p75-video-height']);
            }
            else if ( empty($_POST['p75-video-height']) )
                delete_post_meta($postID, '_videoheight');
        }

    }

    /**
     * The shortcode for embedding videos in your posts wherever.
     *
     * The shortcode accepts four parameters:
     *  id: some post ID, defaults the current post
     *  url: a URL to a video, defaults to null
     *  width: the player width, only works when specifying the URL
     *  height: the player height, only works when specifying the URL
     *
     * If you specify the post ID, it will use the video, width, and height
     * associated with the post.
     *
     * If you specify the video URL, it will use that URL to create the embedded player.
     * If width and height are specified as well, they will be used, otherwise the
     * defaults will be used as set in the options page.
     */
    function p75_video_short_code($atts, $content=null) {
        global $post, $wp_embed;

        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'id' => $post->ID,
            'url' => null,
            'width' => -1,
            'height' => -1
        ), $atts));

        // If a URL is passed in, use that.
        if ( null != $url ) {
            $width = (-1 != $width) ? $width : get_option('p75_default_player_width');
            $height = (-1 != $height) ? $height : get_option('p75_default_player_height');

            return $wp_embed->shortcode( array('width' => $width, 'height' => $height), $url );
        }

        // No URL was passed in.
        return p75GetVideo($id);
    }

    add_shortcode('simple_video', 'p75_video_short_code');

    function p75_videoOptionsAdmin()
    {
    ?>
        <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Simple Video Embedder Options</h2>

            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php
                    wp_nonce_field('update-options');
                    if( get_option('p75_post_types') == "" ){
                        $post_type_value = 'post';
                    }else{
                        $post_type_value = get_option('p75_post_types');
                    }
                ?>

                <table class="form-table">
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th style="white-space:nowrap;" scope="row"><label for="p75_post_types"><?php _e("Enabled for post types"); ?>:</label></th>
                        <td><input id="p75_post_types" type="text" name="p75_post_types" value="<?php echo $post_type_value; ?>" /></td>
                        <td style="width:100%;">The post types (post,page,custom_post_type) that this plugin is enabled for. Use commas to separate with no spaces.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th style="white-space:nowrap;" scope="row"><label for="p75_default_player_width"><?php _e("Default player width"); ?>:</label></th>
                        <td><input id="p75_default_player_width" type="text" name="p75_default_player_width" value="<?php echo get_option('p75_default_player_width'); ?>" /></td>
                        <td style="width:100%;">The default width of the video player if not set.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th style="white-space:nowrap;" scope="row"><label for="p75_default_player_height"><?php _e("Default player height"); ?>:</label></th>
                        <td><input id="p75_default_player_height" type="text" name="p75_default_player_height" value="<?php echo get_option('p75_default_player_height'); ?>" /></td>
                        <td>The default height of the video player if not set.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th style="white-space:nowrap;" scope="row"><label for="p75_jw_files"><?php _e("JW Player files location"); ?></label>:</th>
                        <td><input id="p75_jw_files" type="text" name="p75_jw_files" value="<?php echo get_option('p75_jw_files'); ?>" /></td>
                        <td>The location of the JW player files relative to your WordPress installation.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th style="white-space:nowrap;" scope="row"><a href="http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/FlashVars" title="<?php _e("What are flashvars?"); ?>" target="_blank"><?php _e("JW Player flashvars"); ?></a>:</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="p75_jw_flashvars" value="<?php echo get_option('p75_jw_flashvars'); ?>" /></td>
                        <td>Extra parameters for JW player. For experienced users.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
                <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="p75_post_types,p75_default_player_width,p75_default_player_height,p75_jw_files,p75_jw_flashvars" />

                <p class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>

    <?php
    }


    function ident_simple_video_plugin($blogopts) {
      $blogopts['simple_video_embedder'] =  array(
            'desc' => __( 'Press75 Simple Video Plugin 1.2' ),
            'readonly' => true,
            'option' => 'simple_video_embedder'
            );
      return $blogopts;
    }

    add_filter('xmlrpc_blog_options', 'ident_simple_video_plugin');

    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------END VIDEO PLUGINS------------*/
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This code will definitely give me something to play with.  This only answered a part of my question... but I found the plugin simple fields which I think should take care of the rest.

Comment: I went back and re-read your post. I think I understand more of what you are asking now: you have 10+ pages that will have more elaborate layouts. You do not want these page layouts to depend on the default page editor. I am going to post an additional anwer.